# Network Security Group for Filezilla(client) connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, filezilla

I am new here.

Few days ago, attended MS azure events, and today registered with Azure (free account).
VM Environment: VM = CentOS 7, apache+php+mysql+vsftpd+phpMyAdmin
everything is up and running, able to visit the "info.php" via its public IP address.
SeLinux = disabled, Firewalld disabled.
my problem is not able to connect this server via Filezilla (PC client). 
from Windows command prompt (FTP/put) is working, able to upload files.
But via Filezilla

```
Status: Connecting to 5x.1xx.1xx.7x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/ftpuser"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PORT 192,168,1,183,234,99
Response:   200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 5x.1xx.1xx.7x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/ftpuser"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PORT 192,168,1,183,234,137
Response:   200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I believe that is because of the Network Security group settings for inbound and outbound rules, need open some port, but not sure, because I tried open 1024-65535 all allow, still not working.

Comment: Do you open port 21, 20 on Azure NSG?

Comment: both tried active mode and passive mode. no help

Comment: No,  you need open port  21 on Azure NSG. If you don't open it, you will get the error. I notice your question, it seems that you don't open them.

Comment: yes. inboud port oallow:  20. 21. 22. 80. 60000-65535  for outbound port allow: 80. 20. 1024-65535

Comment: If you use pasv FTP, you should open port that you need on Inbound rules. `pasv_min_port=40001
pasv_max_port=40009`, you need open port 40001-40009 on Azure NSG.

Comment: Don't need open ports on Outbound rules, by default, outbound allows all ports.

Comment: wow, Walter, amazing, you saved my day. thank you very much. I tried allow port from 40001-40009, now is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use passive mode FTP, you should open ports 20,21 and ports that you need on Azure NSG(Inbound rules). You could check `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=60001
pasv_max_port=60005
```

For this example, you should open ports 60001-60005 on Azure NSG(Inbound rules).